# screen not chnaging from splash screen to main activity? Java android studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java android development and i am trying to add splash screen before main activity so i created a splash screen class . and in my android manifest i did the following changes:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.mayoenglishconversation.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mayoenglishconversation.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

and here is the code of my SplashScreen.java file:

```
package com.example.mayoenglishconversation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle 
 persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i=new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    },3000);
}
 }
```

but issue is i am stuck with the splash screen . what i am doing wrong?

Comment: is your main activity have any crash?

Comment: no if i update this line :  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> Under MainActivity in manifest everything works well

Comment: Try to override "protected void onCreate" method instead of "public void onCreate".

Comment: Can you please upload your styles or themes xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the override method `protected void onCreate` instead of `public void onCreate`. I faced this issue previously, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

try to use following `override` method;

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }
```